# Assigning more than one attribute to an object

Tags: c#, xml, list, dictionary, xna

In my game, it has an objective of becoming somewhat like Guitar Hero, however I did make the game before and I crossed many errors in the parsing of the XML. It would read something like this:

```
<song>
  <note>
    <time>1.35</time>
    <key>A</key>
  </note>
</song>
```

And from there, I'd parse each "note" attribute in the XML file and sort it into a dictionary which contains all the notes:

```
public Dictionary<int, string> AssortedNotes = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

And then from there, I'd run a simple ForEach statement, and depending on the value, sort it into sub-categoried dictionaries, such as:

```
public Dictionary<int, string> ANotes = new Dictionary<int, string>();
public Dictionary<int, string> SNotes = new Dictionary<int, string>();
public Dictionary<int, string> DNotes = new Dictionary<int, string>();

public Dictionary<int, string> JNotes = new Dictionary<int, string>();
public Dictionary<int, string> KNotes = new Dictionary<int, string>();
public Dictionary<int, string> LNotes = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

However, here comes the 'dodgy' bit, I inserted the 'time' attribute as the key because if I set the 'key' attribute as the key, for sure I would get errors. My time attribute was based purely on making sure the time was different each and every time. Now with the song maker I produced, this created an issue, of which I had to sort through the XML file and remove any duplicates that may of been in there, now that was a pain.

I know that there are better ways to do something like this, however I am unsure of how. Would somebody please be able to show me a better way of doing things, and then explain how and why that's done?

Thankyou very much,
Jarrod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that I don't completely understand is why do you store time values as `int`? I am convinced that `TimeSpan` would server you better.

Regarding duplicates, you don't really go through a source file and delete them manually. When you try to add duplicate to a dictionary in C# it will throw an `ArgumentException` and you can just ignore it.

Now for storing data. I imagine that the flow of the game would be similar like in Guitar Hero. With that in mind, why don't just use a `List`? Do you need to be able to take data from a collection based on data itself (the capability that `Dictionary` provides)? I don't really understand why you split data to more dictionaries, if you could explain that, maybe I would have advised you otherwise.

Just create a class for storing pairs of values (struct would be definitely better if there is to many of the input data or the speed is important) and store it in `List`. If you need that spliting, just cycle through the list and split it. It make much more sense to fetch data from a collection in the order.

If input data comes not ordered, you can used some of sorted collections available, but that is really not necessary.

Finally, it is still a little bit hard to point you in the right direction not knowing more about what you really need to accomplish.

Comment: iwould not just let the dictionary throw an exception, you should use the Contains method to detect duplicates.

Comment: Thankyou very much, your answer was very helpful. Sorry for the late reply.